Confusion about almost surely convergence
The sequence of function, $\{f_{n}(x)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is said to converge almost surely to the function $f(x)$, if:
$P(\{x;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x) = f(x)\}) =1$.
To check it is a well-defined notion, I need to know the measurability of $\{x;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x) = f(x)\}$
I know if we have two measurable functions $h$ and $g$, then $\{x;h=g\}$ is measurable and $\limsup f_n$ and $\liminf f_n$ are measurable while $\lim f_n$ may not since it may not exist.
So here Does it mean that first $f_n$ has limit for any points in the domain? Then of course $\lim f_n$ is measurable and apply the above proposition, we have the result.

$\lim f_n(x)$ exists and equals $f(x)$ for all points $x$ except possibly for points on a set of measure $0$.

The set in question is ${\limsup f_n -\liminf f_n=0}\cap {\limsup f_n -f=0}$. If $f$ is measurable and $f_n$ are too, then this is measurable.
